# Building an API and Desktop app with electron

Tags: api, electron

Is it possible to build an electron Desktop app frontend and API within the electron platform without having to separate the api and the Front end. I am doing this to avoid having to ask users to install two files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could potentially wrap an API server and a frontend into a single Electron application.

Essentially your server could be spun up within the main process. Then you could use your frontend/renderer process to make calls to your API similar to a website.

Comment: If you are familiar with Express, then this is a good project resource to show you how the two can be integrated. https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express